# SSAS Cube : How to expand a particular level of dimension from pivot table

Tags: excel, ssas, powerpivot, cube

How can I expand a particular level of dimension from a pivot table. Currently when I select a particular dimension, all other dimensions on the same level also expand which causes long processing time. Need advise please. Thank you

[image: Pivot Table Issue]

Answer (score 1):

I've searched for this solution forever with no luck.

Since you must be connecting directly to the cube, you would have to create unique fields in your Dimension table so that they can be expanded/collapsed properly. I've had to use this as a work around for management reporting. It's obviously not the best option storing more data in your table.

[image: Excel]

Comment: thank you Manderson for the confirmation and workaround